Is softmax the same as vector normalization in 3D graphics?
I just found out about the softmax function in machine learning. It creates even probabilistic distribution out of a vector of numbers, which means that all numbers up to 1.
It sounds a lot like the vector normalization that gives a vector of length 1 in 3D graphics (linear algebra).
Can anyone explain the difference between those two ? I hope this is not a silly question and I get the answer.

Try applying softmax to the vector $v = (2,2,1)$, then try normalizing $v$ and compare the results. These are just two different things.

Probability & SoftMax :
Positive numbers , Zeros , negative numbers , large numbers , small numbers can all occur in a vector.
When the numbers represent various Possibilities of some Entity , we want to know which Possibility is most likely for that Entity.
Heuristically , we want to choose the largest number out of those various Possibilities.
Hence , we hand-wave & say these are Probabilities.
BUT , the numbers might be Negative & might add up to some invalid total , which is a requirement for Probabilities.
SOLUTION : Convert to "SoftMax" , where the new numbers are Positive & will add up to $1$ total , looking like Pseudo-Probabilities.
Vector Normalization :
Positive numbers , Zeros , negative numbers , large numbers , small numbers can all occur in a vector.
We want a new vector which fits in the Unit N-Dimensional Ball.
Divide though-out [[ Shrinking/Scaling Operation ]] by the Norm to get that.
The new Unit Vector has Norm $1$.
Sum of Components will not be $1$.
There might still be Negative Components & Zero Components.
Hence it will generally not match SoftMax.
